# How to create simple triagle pattern in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to output a triangle like this one:

19283765
2837465
37465
465
5

However, my actual output looks like this instead:

98765
8765
765
65
5

```
public class JavaNumber2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int r = 9; 


        for (int g = 9; g <= r; g--) {


            for (int j = g; j >= 5; j--) {
                System.out.print(j);
            }

            System.out.println();
        }


    }
}
```

How can I modify this so that I get the first output instead?

Comment: sorry I new to this, I want to input like this one:

19283765
2837465
37465
465
5
image link: https://imgur.com/a/wLwzHwM

Comment: Can you explain how to generate those numbers? I don't see any rule.

Comment: Where is `4` in the first row? Should it be 192837465, shouldn't it?

Comment: it shoul be look like that , I am thinking looping from 1 to 3 and 9 to 5 then combining them , but I dont have Idea how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition in the first for loop is wrong `g<=r` should be `g>=0`, and one `if` condition to print in reverse order.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int r = 9; 


        for (int g = 9; g >=0; g--) {


            for (int j = g; j >= 5; j--) {
                if(g==9) {
                    if(j>6) {
                        System.out.print(r+1-j);
                    }
                }else {
                    if(j>5) {
                        System.out.print(r+1-j);
                    }
                }
                System.out.print(j);

            }

            System.out.println();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thank you, but the output on the first line shouldn't have "4":

Answer (score 0):

I have this answer:

```
public class T2Tree {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    for (int i = 5; i >0; i--) {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            System.out.print(j+1+5-i);
            if (j<i-1) {
                System.out.print(9-j+i-5);
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: thanks but ,it shouldn't have number _4_ on the first row :)

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use a recursion (works with any start and end as well):

```
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        int left = 1;
        int right = 9;

        while(right >= left){
            r(left, right);
            System.out.println();

            left++;
            right--;
        }
    }

    private static void r(int left, int right){
        System.out.print(left);
        if(left != right){
            System.out.print(right);    
        }

        if(right > left){
            r(left + 1, right - 1);
        }
    }
}
```